# DPKG is not responding

Tags: 14.04, apt, wine, dpkg

I was installing wine in my Ubuntu 14.04. I got a pop-up and It was not responding . So, I have closed the Terminal. Then after when ever I am trying to execute

```
sudo apt-get install
```

then I am getting following error:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Can any body help me out in this?

Comment: Problem solved after executing "sudo dpkg --configure -a" .

Comment: Please write an answer to your question and mark it as accepted so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy of comment to close the question (please accept)

Problem solved after executing

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: If the OP found an answer by himself, he should also write the answer himself and accept it in order to close the question.

Comment: I originally thought of writing that, but how long is it going to take for a reputation 1 user to do that and how many people are going to look at a question without answer in the mean time??? ;)
**And if he does just that, I'll delete my answer!!!**

Comment: @the_Seppi: Converted to community wiki (which is what I've been doing recently when the answer wasn't mine)